# I need help for this program

Tags: python-3.x

You're playing battleships, but you keep forgetting which squares in the grid you've already selected! Write a program to help you keep track of which squares you've hit. Your program should read in coordinates, one per line. If you haven't tried that square before, your program should print out Hit . If you have tried those coordinates already, you should print out You've chosen that square already.
Your program should run until a blank line is entered, and should work like this:

```
Guess: A3
Hit A3
Guess: C4
Hit C4
Guess: A3
You've chosen that square already
Guess: B2
Hit B2
Guess:
```

Comment: Do not expect us to do your homework, try it first then come back

Comment: It looks like you're asking for the complete solution to an assignment. This kind of question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. You'll have to try to code something on your own first, then when you get stuck on your own attempt, come back here with a [summary of the work you've done so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to solve the problem so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which performs the desired tasks. Keep in mind, there is no error checking that comes along with this and it is not actually checking the inputs against some set of tiles where the enemy is located.

```
def battleship():
    guesses = []
    while True:
        guess = str(input("Guess: "))
        if guess in guesses:
            print("You've chosen that square already")
        else:
            print("Hit {0}".format(guess))
            guesses.append(guess)
```

example output:

```
>>> battleship()
Guess: A3
Hit A3
Guess: C4
Hit C4
Guess: A3
You've chosen that square already
Guess: B2
Hit B2
Guess:
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with your homework:

```
Hit_Square = []
user_input = ()

while user_input != "":
  user_input = input("Guess: ")
  if user_input == "":
    break
  if user_input not in Hit_Square:   

    Hit_Square.append(user_input)
    print ("Hit", user_input)

  else: 
       print("You've chosen that square already")
```